# Locked ViewController orientation breaking when segueing back and forth

Tags: ios, swift, orientation, appdelegate

I have a simple camera app. 
The Camera Preview screen is a viewcontroller (name ViewController) which I locked the orientation via
this code (can't find the StackOverflow link to this code), The viewcontroller is embedded in a navigation controller:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
            if navigationController.visibleViewController is ViewController {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
            } else {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
            }
        }
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    }
```

When the camera starts up, the Camera Preview is locked in .portrait orientation, which is what I desire. 
However, if I hit the library button, which segues me to another screen,
and change the orientation of the library screen by rotating my physical device, and THEN return back to my Camera Preview screen via the "back" button, the orientation is broken. It's in landscape mode, instead of portrait mode. 
How do I get a hard lock?

Just incase, I made a dummy model of my code here (too long to post here), where you guys can test it out yourself

https://github.com/bigmit2011/Testing-Camera

EDIT:

If the app crashes just try running it one more time. 
For some reason the first time the app is ran it crashes. Thank you.

EDIT2:

Attempting to set embedded ViewController as a delegate of UINavigationController.
However, I don't quite understand if I'm doing it correctly:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var navigation: UINavigationController?
    self.navigation.delegate = self  // doesn't seem to work


    func navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations(_ navigationController: UINavigationController) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

        return .portrait
    }
```

Do I need to create a separate swift file for the UiNavigationController?

EDIT3:
Following Matt's answer code is as follows:

```
class CameraViewController :UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.navigationController?.delegate = self
    super.viewDidLoad()

func navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations(_ navigationController: UINavigationController) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

        return .portrait
    }
```

However, this seems to lock everything in portrait mode not just that single viewController embedded within Navigation Controller.

Comment: your project crashes

Comment: @Vyacheslav Try running it one more time please. For some reason the first time the app is ran it crashes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also couldn't run your app. But I tested this in Xcode with a main VC, a 2nd VC and embedded the main VC in a navigation controller.  I then followed the advice in this article [Selective rotation lock in iOS](https://gunnarhafdal.com/2017/01/selective-rotation-lock-in-ios-apps-with-swift.html)

You add the following to AppDelegate:

```
var enableAllOrientation = false

func application(_ application: UIApplication,supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
if (enableAllOrientation == true){
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.allButUpsideDown
}
return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
}
```

Then in the VC that allows allButUpsideDown (or change this to what you want), you add the following code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.enableAllOrientation = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.enableAllOrientation = false

let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue
UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
}
```

I put this in the 2nd VC. Ran the app in the simulator, segued to the 2nd VC, changed the orientation to landscape then hit back and the main VC was locked in portrait.

Comment: Thank you. When you say "Then in the app that allows allButUpsideDown (or change this to what you want), you add the following code" , do you mean viewcontroller and not "app".  Does this mean I have to add this every single viewcontroller that I don't want to lock?  Going to test it out.  As for the app crashing, it always crashes the first time, but the second time is usually fine. It's another bug I have to sort out eventually.

Comment: Good catch on "the app" needing to be "VC".  I edited this.  And, yes, you need to add this code to each VC that goes against the app delegate setting (which in this example is false for all orientations and set to portrait only)

Comment: This works great. I just switched `var enableAllOrientation = false` to true, so that I only have to change one view controller.

Answer (score 2):

You are making two mistakes.

- First, you are trying to govern the orientation of individual view controllers from the app delegate. That's wrong. The app delegate governs the totality of *possible* orientations for the *whole* app. But as for view controllers, each individual view controller governs its *own* orientation. Just implement `supportedInterfaceOrientations` in each of your two view controllers (not in the app delegate).
- Second, your first view controller is in a navigation interface. Therefore it is not the top-level view controller and cannot govern orientation directly (with `supportedInterfaceOrientations`). The correct way to govern the orientation of a navigation interface is to set yourself as the navigation controller's *delegate* and implement `navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations(_:)`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm having trouble setting the ViewController as the navigation controller's delegate correctly. See my attempt in OP, under EDIT2. I would appreciate it you teach me how to do so properly.  I can't find any examples on the web on how to do so properly when it comes to navigation controllers. 

Thank you.

Comment: @Moondra https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621860-navigationcontroller

Comment: I've already looked at the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621860-navigationcontroller

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontrollerdelegate/1621884-navigationcontrollersupportedint

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinterfaceorientationmask

That's how I was able to get to  my example above. 
However, I don't see any examples in the docs, so I'm having trouble understanding how to get it working properly. Thank you.

Comment: So the docs are not enough to allow you to formulate the phrase `self.navigationController?.delegate = self`

Comment: I've looked at the docs and I couldn't figure it out. I even gave a working example of what I tried to do based on what you said. Please spare me your condescending attitude.

Comment: Well you can’t just put that line in the middle of nowhere like that. It needs to be in your `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Just did so. However, your method seems to be locking everything in `.portrait`mode. Please see EDIT3.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by everything. In your question there are just two view controllers. One of them presents the other. Each needs its own implementation for setting the supported orientations, as I said in my answer. They will then be able to rotate differently from each other.